# Wordpress loop looping four times but only displaying one record

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields, visual-composer

Ok I am trying to get a custom post type working with a couple of fields for the most part it works and outputs the data but instead of each team member it is display the same team member multiple times.

```
function team(){


// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'team-member'

);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 

  while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  
  ?>
        <sction class="row ev-home-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12 owl-carousel owl-theme" id="teams">
        <div class="item ev-home-4-block">



            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field('photo'); ?>" class="img-responsive" />

                <div class="row row2 ev-home-4-block-2">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <small><?php the_field('description'); ?></small>
                </div>
            </a>
                </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </sction>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK5Op.jpg

I dont have a rep of ten so dont no how to add an image sorry about that.

**Edit 2** 
Screen shot to show different data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH1Pi.jpg

Screen shot to show differnt photos for data

Teammember 1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmT2B.jpg

Team Member 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChN4.jpg

The above is what it should be printing out.

**Edit 3**
Ok So i have the team members showing fine now but its showing one below another instead of left to right

```
function team(){


$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('team-member'), 
  'post_status' => 'publish', 
  'order' => 'DESC', 
  'orderby' => 'date', 
  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
  'paged' => $paged, 
);



// WP_Query
$eq_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($eq_query->have_posts()) : // The Loop
?>

<sction class="row ev-home-4"> 
<?php 

while ($eq_query->have_posts()): $eq_query->the_post();
?>

           <div class="item ev-home-4-block" style="float:left;">
            <img src="<?php the_field('photo'); ?>" class="img-responsive" />

                                <div class="row row2 ev-home-4-block-2">

                                <h2><?php the_field('name'); ?></h2>
                                <small><?php the_field('desciption'); ?></small>
                            </div>

                            </div>




 </div>



<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> 

<?php include(EQ_PAGING); ?>

<?php endif;  




    return $cnt;
}
add_shortcode('team','team');
```

As you see here it is showing it below the other pic when they should be to the right of each other

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Yme.jpg

Comment: Have you **definitely** assigned unique images in the ACF field to each post? And not just set unique images in the 'featured image' part, for example?

Comment: @ProEvilz Yes I have and content let me show you

Comment: @ProEvilz please see above edits

Comment: first of it, it should be `'posts_per_page'=>-1,` not `numberposts`

Comment: @ProEvilz yes they are not on the featured image ! it wouldnt find that image their anyway ! its a unique field called photo !

Comment: Please amend your code with what I wrote above then do a `var_dump($the_query);`  and paste the output in your post

Comment: As you see its not just the photo is getting repeated its the data as well so this is not just a photo issues @ProEvilz

Comment: It's almost like you're not reading what I'm putting. I know it's a problem with the data. Please follow my steps or I can't help.

Comment: @ProEvilz why would I want post per page surley i want all showing

Comment: `numberposts` is not the right way to do it, `posts_per_page` is. The `-1` means show ALL posts... that's why you've got it set to `-1` with `numberposts` to begin with.

Comment: @ProEvilz Please find the var dump here it is indead getting the two records fine https://pastebin.com/R0yFvi5U but i changed the code and its still outputting the same record 4 times dont get this

Comment: Hmm yes this is odd. Please dump the post variable it's self too

Comment: @ProEvilz its something to do with the 4 block for some reason i have it outputting two now but not the way it was

Comment: @ProEvilz have a look at above edit see if you can tell what going on

Comment: You have a typo `'sction'` and you shouldn't have to write all that out for this.

Comment: Post the code for your CPT and export the ACF fields for this CPT with XML format as the choice. I'll go off and create a simpler script and report back